# Binary logistic regression- enter vs. all at once

Tags: regression, logistic, binary-data, predictor

I have a question regarding binary logistic regression.
My DV is dichotomous (0=no, 1=yes), and I have 9 predictor variables (dummy-coded & scale). 
If I do for each predictor one regression analysis, some of them are significant.
But as soon as I enter one predictor with other predictors, they loose their significance levels.
My question: WHY?? I now that they depend on each other, but I really do not get why this happens.

And my second question: Is it ok to run separate logistic regression for the same DV?

THANKS FOR ANSWERS :-)

Comment: Stepwise variable selection is an invalid method - don't even consider it for your problem.  Formulate a model based on subject matter understanding and stick to that model.  Estimate its parameters and especially get confidence intervals for effects on meaningful scales.  The full prespecified model should be the basis for all of your inference.

Comment: Thank you Frank! 
So if I am only interested in the influence of one IV on the the DV (indecent of other variables), is it legitimate to run separate logistic regressions (simple binary logistic regressions)?

Comment: No.  Pre-specify a sensible model, fit it, and draw inference on the partial effect of the one variable of major interest (adjusted for all the others).

Answer (score 0):

Because when you have more than one independent variable in the model, the model is controlling for those other variables.  So, you are asking different questions and getting different answers.

Comment: Thanks Peter,
Does this mean that if I am only interested in each predictor separately (and not interested in the influence on each other) I can run separate logistic regressions?

Comment: It would be very unusual to not be interested in the effects of controlling for other variables.  Especially, as in your case, when they are related to each other.